# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED while trying to install "requests-kerberos" via pip

Tags: python, ssl, pip, ssl-certificate, kerberos

In my mac machine, when I try to install requests-kerberos I am getting below error,

```
% pip install requests-kerberos    

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1002)'))': /simple/requests-kerberos/
```

Any inputs are welcome.